# USB to Ethernet adapter configuration in Linux

Tags: ethernet, port-forwarding

I have a USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet Network Adapter UE306. I want to connect my Arduino board which has RJ45 using that adapter to Ubuntu over USB to give internet access to Arduino board. I do not want to give direct Ethernet access.

So it is like, Internet->Ubuntu->USB(UE306)->(UE306)RJ45->Arduino

I tried port forwarding as mentioned [here in the Manjaro Forums](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/share-internet-using-usb-to-ethernet-adapter/122146/2) but I do not want static IP address. I want dynamic address for both UE306 and Arduino board.

Any suggestions?